# Should these two tags be combined [bll] and [business-logic-layer]?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, synonym-request

Following is Tag Info for [bll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bll) (107 questions):

> About bll
>
> A Business Logic Layer (BLL) is a typical software engineering
>   artifact within a Multitier architecture. A Business Logic Layer (BLL)
>   is a typical software engineering artifact within a Multitier
>   architecture. It separates the business logic from other tiers, such
>   as the data access layer or service layer. BLL objects are typically
>   partitioned into two categories: business process objects (those which
>   reflect business activities, or behaviors) and business entities
>   (those which reflect real world business objects). Business process
>   objects are typically implemented as controllers, i.e. they contain no
>   data elements and only expose behaviors and activities which represent
>   business processes. Business entities typically correspond to entities
>   in a domain model rather than a database model.

Following is Tag Info for [business-logic-layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/business-logic-layer) (200 questions):

> About business-logic-layer
>
> The business logic layer (BLL) is the layer in a multi-layer software
>   architecture which separates the business logic from other layers such
>   as the data access layer (DAL) and user interface (UI or presentation
>   layer). A business logic layer (BLL) is a software engineering
>   practice of compartmentalizing business rules in a multitier
>   architecture. It separates the business logic from other modules, such
>   as the data access layer (DAL) and user interface (UI). By doing this,
>   the business logic of an application can often withstand modifications
>   or replacements of other tiers.

When I search for questions tagged with one I get different questions list as output when I search for other. In my understanding, both tags represent same thing even though their Tag Info is bit different. Each tag info contains reference to other tag as a short (BLL) or long (Business Logic Layer) form.

Should these two tags be combined?

Comment: lol, who comes up with all these TLA tags? IMO, the long version is almost always better except perhaps in cases like AWS, where its more or less universally recognized. Combine ASAP!

Comment: @code11 The acronyms have practically become the proper names for many of Amazon's services. For instance, compare usage of "Simple Storage Service" and "Elastic Compute Cloud" to their more common names, "S3" and "EC2"…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), I've synonymized both the posts in the following direction

[business-logic-layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/business-logic-layer) ← [bll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bll)

At the time of the synonymization, the tags had 202 and 107 posts respectively.