# Should the tag [tdd] be renamed to [test-driven-development]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

Should the tag [tdd] be renamed to [test-driven-development]?

Tag [tdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tdd) is used for Test Driven Development. Tag with name "test-driven-development" does not exists.

I generally see tag names on SO with longer version. I also read somewhere on meta that this is recommended.

The similar tag [domain-driven-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/domain-driven-design) follows same rule.

Comment: I thought that tag stood for Test Driven _Development_ not Design.

Comment: @George: Sorry; my bad. Just corrected.

Comment: Why is it a problem? Do many questions get mis-tagged?

Comment: @rene: "I generally see tag names on SO with longer version. I also read somewhere on meta that this is recommended."

Comment: A reference to that meta post would help. I would be very reluctant to simply rename tags (or take any action for that matter) if there isn't a proven problem. Meta post are not to be used as a law and certainly don't need enforcement if there isn't a problem.

Comment: @rene: I do not remember if it was an answer or comment on [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345073/5779732) question which is now deleted. You can surely view deleted answers. I am not sure if deleted comments are visible to you.

Comment: there is already a [synonym defined](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tdd/synonyms). And that post you refer to is to synomise two existing tags. What you propose here is a plain rename. That is different in my opinion and the post you link to is not supportive for this case.

Comment: @rene: Is'nt that [tag:testdrivendevelopment] bit unreadable? The one I proposed separates the words with "-" which makes it more readable. I also see many tags on SO with this convention. I mentioned one example in question.

Comment: You won't get testdrivendevelopment as suggestion when you add tags so if it is good readable or not is a non-issue. I did find that [tag:testdrivendesign] does exist ...

Answer (score 6):

No.

I don't see any issue with using the common abbreviation TDD nor do I see much confusion in the usage of that tag.

There is already a synonym in place to change [testdrivendevelopment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testdrivendevelopment) to [tdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tdd). Renaming [testdrivendevelopment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testdrivendevelopment) will not help much as the synonym don't popup when you edit or add a tag.

For this specific case I don't see an immediate need to make such change, nor am I aware of a policy that abbreviations are always to be avoided. Ambiguous tag meanings need to be fixed but not is not limited to abbreviations.

To be complete, we also have [testdrivendesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testdrivendesign). Not sure if that tag requires our attention or a rename as you suggest.

Comment: Is my wording in question incorrect? Should I say "create synonym" instead of "rename"? I am not much active on tag related meta posts; so I do not know the internals. About "policy" part, I surely remember I read it somewhere on meta. Tried to find a lot without success.

Comment: I was about to ask a question about TDD and started typing "test-d" in tags box because most of the tags follow that naming convention. When no results found, I tried "tdd" and that was it. My question focuses on aligning the naming convention of tag. How to do that? I am not much aware. That is why, question is tagged [discussion] instead of request.

Comment: renaming and sysnonyms are different things from my perspective but I can see the confusion it might give. Feel free to re-formulate to a synonym request, assuming you can't suggest a synonym yourself.